# swarm mode doesn't recognize absolute path in windows

Tags: powershell, docker-swarm, git-bash, docker-machine, cmder

I am following Bret Fisher's docker course and I got [this assignment](https://github.com/BretFisher/udemy-docker-mastery/tree/main/swarm-app-1). I am running on windows and created 3 virtual nodes with docker-machine. All three nodes are connected in a swarm (2 managers, 1 worker). I am trying to run the following command:

`docker service create --network backend --mount type=volume,source=db-data,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data --name db -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres:9.4`

when I run in powershell, It works fine.
When I try to run it in GitBash or cmder I get the error:

`invalid mount target, must be an absolute path <the path of cli in used>`

I tried to change the target to:

1. different paths
2. `pwd/ $pwd / $(pwd) / ${pwd}`
3. `wsl wslpath $(pwd)`

p.s.
When I run [the stack example](https://github.com/BretFisher/udemy-docker-mastery/blob/main/swarm-stack-1/example-voting-app-stack.yml) of the same code, it does run in GitBash/ Cmder and powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try quoting the mount value?

```
docker service create --network backend --mount "type=volume,source=db-data,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data" --name db -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres:9.4
```

Comment: yes, I tried with and without quotes (double and single). This feels like an environment problem or a bug

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are working in a directory that contains spaces.

When using mounts and volumes (`-v`), Docker cannot handle this case with Bash on Windows, no matter which escape characters you try.

The only way I found to solve this is to switch your current directory to one in which no folder contains spaces.

Even the use of `$(pwd)` inside `-v` input is a problem, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67473985/cannot-map-a-host-directory-with-spaces-to-a-container-directory-bind-mounts), there is also a list of escape characters I tried to use to solve the problem.