# Cannot map a host directory with spaces to a container directory (bind mounts) - Docker Quickstart Terminal (Bash), windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, spaces, mounted-volumes, docker-quickstart-terminal

I am a newbie with Docker. I am following a tutorial in which I am using bind mounts and volumes, I am using windows 10 Docker quickstart terminal (bash) and Docker 19.03.1.

I am in the directory `.../dockerfile-sample-2` (**Note**: this path contains spaces) containing:

```
$ ls -al
total 18
drwxr-xr-x 1 Tommaso 197121   0 mag 10 11:55 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 Tommaso 197121   0 mag  1 19:20 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tommaso 197121 410 apr 11 09:06 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tommaso 197121 249 apr 11 09:06 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tommaso 197121   0 mag 10 11:55 testme.txt
```

Now I run and get the followings:

```
.../dockerfile-sample-2
$ docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
b8f24ee0e0b76d0b06503ce90fbd6a9e2110e40eaa4432e8c77556510c61a989

.../dockerfile-sample-2
$ docker container run -d --name nginx2 -p 8080:80 nginx
3450433e18097291936d7e62071769521eb36e92f509ad931c9e927f135df71a
```

Now, according to the tutorial, by accessing the IP addresses http://192.168.99.101/ and http://192.168.99.101:8080, I should be able to see, respectiverly, a custom landing page from the **index.html** file and the original nginx landing page.

However, I only get the original nginx landing page twice.

And more, according to my tutorial, by running

```
docker container exec -it nginx bash
cd /usr/share/nginx/html
ls –al
```

I should get the same content of the previous directory `.../dockerfile-sample-2`.

However, I only get

```
root@b8f24ee0e0b7:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 13 19:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 13 19:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  494 Apr 13 15:13 50x.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  612 Apr 13 15:13 index.html
```

and again, according to my tutorial, if I'd make a new file in my `.../dockerfile-sample-2` directory, it should appear among the results of

```
docker container exec -it nginx bash
cd /usr/share/nginx/html
ls –al
```

but it does not.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Here you have some context:

My **running containers**:

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
3450433e1809        nginx               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   nginx2
b8f24ee0e0b7        nginx               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp     nginx
```

In my **Dockerfile:**

```
# this shows how we can extend/change an existing official image from Docker Hub
FROM nginx:latest
# highly recommend you always pin versions for anything beyond dev/learn

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
# change working directory to root of nginx webhost
# using WORKDIR is preferred to using 'RUN cd /some/path'

COPY index.html index.html

# I don't have to specify EXPOSE or CMD because they're in my FROM
```

In my **Index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Your 2nd Dockerfile worked!</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>You just successfully ran a container with a custom file copied into the image at build time!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I bet the problem is related to the fact that the current working directory contains spaces.

So I removed the nginx container and tryed run other ones.

The following commands:

```
docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -v "$(pwd)":/usr/share/nginx/html nginx

docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -v "/d/Files Tommaso/Programmazione/Docker/udemy-docker-mastery-main/dockerfile-sample-2:/usr/share/nginx/html" nginx

docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -v "/d/Files Tommaso/Programmazione/Docker/udemy-docker-mastery-main/dockerfile-sample-2":/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

as I try to access `http://192.168.99.101/`, make my browser get **403 Forbidden**.

---

while these other commands:

```
docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html nginx

docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -v /$(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html nginx

docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -v `pwd -W`:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx

docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html nginx

docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -v /d/Files Tommaso/Programmazione/Docker/udemy-docker-mastery-main/dockerfile-sample-2:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

make my terminal respond with:

```
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

I bet this means it cannot parse spaces.

---

and these other commands:

```
docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -v %cd%:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

make my terminal respond with:

```
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: create YYYY: "YYYY" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
```

Comment: Your first command bind mounts to `/us/share/...`, without a `r` in `/usr/`; is that a typo in the question?

Comment: yes, the typo is just in the question. I removed the containers and did the whole tour again, and I get the same problem. I updated the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `--mount` will solve the issue
`docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",destination=/usr/share/nginx/html nginx`

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts I can assume that

- on windows 10
- using Docker Quickstart Terminal

Docker 19.03.1 cannot manage the use of `<path containing spaces>` inside `-v` parameter

```
docker container run -d --name <name> -p 80:80 -v <path containing spaces>:<destination path> <image>
```

The only way I found to solve this problem is to change the source volume directory to a directory in which no folder contains spaces, and running

```
docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into pretty much the same problem (given assumptions of spacing in directory causing problems) when binding `directory:volume` using `-v`.

Context: 
running an aws lambda function deployment package build task container using `lambci/lambda:build-python3.8` image, utilising files in `windowspath\build`.

The following command worked for me, in the sense that files in `windowspath\build` were recognised and used for the following `/bin/sh -c` commands; therefore binding to `/var/task` worked as intended.

**Note:** after `-v` flag, double quotes only for the source directory [(windows style pathing](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/troubleshoot/#path-conversion-on-windows), supposedly would work for unix style as well), end double quotes before the colon, directory `/var/task` referred after colon is the docker run environment directory (unix style/WSL backend).

```
docker run -v "C:\windowspath\build":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t package/;cd package;zip -r ../deployment_package.zip .;zip -g ../deployment_package.zip ../lambda_function.py"
```

Comment: cheers to @Tms91 for the formatting my answer for readability!